# Escape quotes from the results of a SQL Server query

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I have this PHP code that executes a query.

```
$sql = "SELECT ACCOUNTNUM as AccountNumber, NAME AS CompanyName
FROM VENDORTABLE";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );

if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
```

And I then use the results from the query to populate a datalist:

```
<form method="POST">

<label for="A">Number/Name:</label><br>
<input list="A" name="name">
<datalist id="A">
  <?php
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) { ?>
      <option value='<?php echo $row[0].",".$row[1] ?>'><?php
    }
  ?>
</datalist><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Continue"">

</form>
```

The problem is some of the results have characters that HTML doesn't like (namely ' and ") and those reults get cut off ("Mike's" becomes "Mike", for example) when the loop puts them into the datalist.

How can I make it so that what gets put into the datalist includes the whole result and any quotes that are present in the data?

I've tried doing this:

```
<?php
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) { ?>
      <option value='<?php echo $row[0].",".htmlspecialchars($row[1]) ?>'><?php
    }
  ?>
```

Also with addslashes() instead of htmlspecialchars(), the former just adds a slash on the first occurrence of a quote but still cuts off everything after that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions:

- Change single quotes to double ones around value attribute.
- Add ENT_QUOTES flag to htmlspecialchars method

`<option value="<?php echo $row[0].",".htmlspecialchars($row[1],ENT_QUOTES) ?>">`

Answer (score 0):

Within HTML attribute values you can use HTML entities, so escape your strings with the [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function:

```
htmlentities($row[1], ENT_QUOTES)
```

Also have a look at the options you can pass to this function.